# How to prevent double authentication of different devices with the same credentials with an API backend?

Tags: android, authentication, api-authorization

I'm working on a project which have an Android part (but in a future there can be other OSes apps as well) worked on devices which must work without user interaction (have limited input capabilities and each user may have a significant number of devices).

So I'm considering the workflow with API request for user approval during the first run (device asks for a temporary authentication token and a user code, shows the code on the screen, then user inputs the code from web interface on different device) and after the approval device gets a request token with a small TTL period and a refresh timeless token with for refresh request tokens only.

The problem is that every device must be uniquelly identified and I can't figure out how to prevent the case when a user will backup all the device system and restore it on another device and then both devices will use the same tokens which were previously issued. Each device will have a long time connection to the server, so in theory I can get rid of refresh tokens, reissue the request token on every connect (and from time to time renew it during the work session if it will going to expire) and prevent the second connections if the first one has already been established.

But what to do in case when device hadn't had connected for a while (longer than last token TTL)? It's impossible to ask the user to enter user code again on every token expiration. If I'll keep refresh tokens then each copy of the original device will ask for a new request token on 'access forbidden'.

Thank you, any help would appreciate.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can first of all disable the possibility to backup the app (but not for rooted devices) or you could use the deviceId (it's unique) to send together with the token for instance. So next time the user tries to use the token, it won't work and the user has to re-authenticate, because the deviceId has changed, as he/she changed device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Darwind! Yes, I thought about deviceId, but couldn't it be faked as well? Preventing backup isn't an option, because device probably will be rooted (otherwise I don't understand how to do mass install\update application with very limited user access, don't think it's a good idea to ask a user to connect to Google Services - but it's another topic, I have yet made any decisions on that).

Comment: I guess you could fake a deviceId if you have a rooted device, but making the tokens expire after a specific amount of time would also fix this issue to some extend. Probably make the tokens shortlived, like a few hours unless the user opens the app again, so the token will be renewed.